# URL with PHP variable

Tags: php, html

In my database table I'm trying to link in a variable here is my current code

```
echo "<td>" . $row['formatted_ts'] . "</td><td>" . $row['marketer'] . "</td><td>" . $row['facility'] . "</td><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['type'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['fax'] . "</td><td>" . $row['description'] . "</td><td>" . $row['locality'] . "</td><td>" . $row['state'] . "</td><td>" . $row['zip'] . "</td><td>" .<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/<?php echo $row['latlng']; ?>"> Link </a> . "</td>";
```

Im not able to get the link to work. In previous table it was working.

```
<td><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/<?php echo $row_leadstammy['latlng']; ?>"> Link </a></td>
```

Comment: Improve code formatting please

Answer (score 3):

You've messed up the html a little bit. Try putting each cell on it's own line, makes it easier to find the solution

```
echo "<td>" . $row['formatted_ts'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['marketer'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['facility'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['fax'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['locality'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['zip'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"https://www.google.com/maps/place/" . $row['latlng'] . "\"> Link </a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of some extra single/ double quotes near your anchor tag and `echo` is being used in `echo`. Try following code:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['formatted_ts'] . "</td><td>" . $row['marketer'] . "</td><td>" . $row['facility'] . "</td><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['type'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['fax'] . "</td><td>" . $row['description'] . "</td><td>" . $row['locality'] . "</td><td>" . $row['state'] . "</td><td>" . $row['zip'] . "</td><td><a href='https://www.google.com/maps/place/". $row['latlng'] ."'> Link </a></td>";
```

OR

Alternatively you can do it as following, which would be much clear to view.

```
echo "<td>" . $row['formatted_ts'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['marketer'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['facility'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['fax'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['locality'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['zip'] . "</td>
<td><a href='https://www.google.com/maps/place/". $row['latlng'] ."'> Link </a></td>";
```

Comment: thats not working either – will you please let us know the exact error message you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

You're already in echo ie, php then why are you doing `<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/<?php echo $row['latlng']; ?>"> Link </a> . "</td>";`

Just use:

`<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/".$row['latlng']`

entire code:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['formatted_ts'] . "</td><td>" . $row['marketer'] . "</td><td>" . $row['facility'] . "</td><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['type'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['fax'] . "</td><td>" . $row['description'] . "</td><td>" . $row['locality'] . "</td><td>" . $row['state'] . "</td><td>" . $row['zip'] . "</td><td><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/".$row['latlng']."> Link </a></td>";
```